# How to substract single string from a sparseArray?

Tags: android, android-sparsearray

I've been working with Android Mobile Vision OCR API for a while. Everything is work perfectly until i found that i need to extract just single words from the whole SparseArray (Mobile Vision API default return is a TextBlocks which defined in a SparseArray)

```
SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlocks = textRecognizer.detect(imageFrame);

  for (int i = 0; i < textBlocks.size(); i++) {

       TextBlock textBlock = textBlocks.get(textBlocks.keyAt(i));
            List<Line> lines = (List<Line>) textBlock.getComponents();
            for (Line line : lines) {
                List<Element> elements = (List<Element>) 
                line.getComponents();
                for (Element element : elements) {
                    word = element.getValue();

                    Log.d(TAG, "word Read : " + word);
                }
            }
        }
```

When i check

`Log.d(TAG, "word Read : " + word);`

it print out repeatedly all element in the SparseArray

[image]

It seems that i'm asking a not-so-obvious question. But can i extract just a single or couple word from those "words" printed above ? For example, i want to extract the word which has character above 12 and has number in it.

Any help or hints will much Appreciated.

Comment: When you say `has character above 12` do you mean `has 12 or more characters`? And when you say `has number in it`, do you mean you want to match a specific number or any number at all?

Comment: Yes, it just a case. What i need is substract a single string from sparseArray which fullfill my certain condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add logical expression to filter result like below:

```
    word = element.getValue();
    if (word .length() > 12 && word .matches("[0-9]+")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "word Read : " + word);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for replying, however, the result "word read" still printed in list of string. I still have no idea how to make it just a single or couple of string instead a list of string

Comment: well i think this is a good-to-go, i was add the if with else {} and it's weird that both if and else condition is activated with sparseArray. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are running word in a loop that's why it's printing all the values. When you run it only once according to the answer of @navylover you will get a single string. Just remove the for loop